# How to check radio buttons based upon returned XML data using an XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, radio-button, checked

Hey I'm pretty new to XSLT's and trying to get my head around using them to produce and populate a form. I have made the XSLT and can get the XML data from the server and I think I have correctly matched up all the fields etc with their respective XML data. However I can't work out how to make radio buttons and checkboxes checked depending on the stored XML data. I have found a couple of similar posts on the net but I cannot make them function correctly and was hoping someone on here might be able to give me a hand.

I have made some small test code with which to try and get this working as I didn't want to risk messing up the full form. The test XML and XSL are shown below.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test2.xsl"?>
<root>
<radiobuttons>
    <radio1>Y</radio1>
    <blurb>blahblahblah</blurb>
</radiobuttons>
</root>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"
            encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<HTML>
<BODY>
<form>
<xsl:apply-templates select="root"/>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">

<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Y" >
<xsl:if test="root/radiobuttons/radio1='Y'">
<xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
</input>Radio Button 1

<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="N" >
<xsl:if test="root/radiobuttons/radio1='N'">
<xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
</input>Radio Button 2

<br/>
<input name="blurb" type="text" id="blurb" value="{./radiotbuttons/blurb}"></input>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd like the first radio button to be checked in the resulting HTML if the XML has a value of Y stored and the 2nd buton if it has a value of N. If anyone can shed some light on why this isn't working or if it is completely the wrong approach then give me a correct example I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have made an error in your xpath

u must remove root/ from "root/radiobuttons/radio1" as at this point you are inside the root node so doesnt really exsist anymore :P

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"
            encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<HTML>
<BODY>
<form>
<xsl:apply-templates select="root"/>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">

<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Y" >
<xsl:if test="radiobuttons/radio1='Y'">
<xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
</input>Radio Button 1

<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="N" >
<xsl:if test="radiobuttons/radio1='N'">
<xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
</input>Radio Button 2

<br/>
<input name="blurb" type="text" id="blurb" value="{./radiobuttons/blurb}"></input>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sigh I can't believe I was that close and made such a stupid mistake. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Also `<input name="blurb">` didn't work because there was and still is a typo in the XPath: radiotbuttons --> radiobuttons.